# Get Remaining Days in MYSQL SELECT (Subtracting 3 datetimes)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to subtract now() - the created datetime field from 30 days to get the days remaining as a datetime field, mysql gives me an error for this sort of thing.

```
SELECT id, created, INTERVAL 30 DAY - CURRENT_DATE - created as timeleft FROM tablename
```

Comment: `INTERVAL 30 DAY - CURRENT_DATE` is backwards... needs to be `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date add function to subtract 30 days like this.

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD(current_date, interval -30 day);
```

Return the difference in days between two date values:

```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(current_date, "2017-06-15");
```

You can use the combination of these functions to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you should translate the datetime to unix_timestamp to calculate the difference between the two days

`SELECT id, created, 30 - (unix_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE) - unix_timestamp(created )) / 3600/24 as timeleft FROM tablename`